# The second catch keeps executing in while loop (Try-Catch)

Tags: java, try-catch

How can I solve it ???

Why the second catch keeps printing in the output console ...

I just mean to print it once and then get back to the loop again if the boolean data type is not true .

```
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);

    int a ,b,result;
    boolean status=false;
    while(!status){
    try{

        a=input.nextInt();
        b=input.nextInt();

        result=a/b;
        status=true;

    }catch (ArithmeticException ex){

        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

    }catch(InputMismatchException ex){

        System.out.println(ex);

    }catch(Exception ex){

        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

    }
    }

}
```

Comment: You have to consume the input that isn't an `int`. Add a `input.nextLine()` in your `catch` block.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Isn't that an answer?

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check my in line comments

```
while(!status){
    try{

        a=input.nextInt();
        b=input.nextInt();

        result=a/b;
        status=true;

    }catch (ArithmeticException ex){

        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

    }catch(InputMismatchException ex){

        System.out.println(ex);
        input.next(); // So when ever InputMismatchException occurs Scanner will not consume the token it will keep that token so we need to consume that by using `next()`
    }catch(Exception ex){

        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());

    }
```

Comment: This works better as he need to get input from scanner infinite time but  in your code also it keeps exiting after your give valid inputs ... loop still exits. i assume he is trying to get input from user infinite time

Answer (score 0):

Add break statement inside catch block which you are using to get all the mismatch inputs

```
catch(InputMismatchException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
            break;
        }
```